# How to construct WebURL from std::wstring?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, awesomium, wstring

I am writing a Win32 application with [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/). According to the tutorial section I can load a local file inside my view:

```
WebURL url(WSLit("file:///C:/dev/project/util/ui/index.html"));
view_->web_view()->LoadURL(url);
```

This works as expected.

When I try to pass an `std::wstring` to `WSList` function:

```
std::wstring ui_path = L"file:///" + install_path + L"/util/ui/index.html";
WebURL url(WSLit(ui_path));
view_->web_view()->LoadURL(url);
```

I get a compiler error:

> src/main.cc(52) : error C2664: 'Awesomium::WSLit' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>       'std::wstring' to 'const char *' No user-defined-conversion operator available that can
>       perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

When I try to pass `WSLit( ui_path.c_str() )` the compiler throws another error:

> src/main.cc(52) : error C2664: 'Awesomium::WSLit' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 
>       'const wchar_t *' to 'const char *'
>       Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or 
>       function-style cast

What is the right way to convert it to `const char *` type?

**Edit:**

From **Awesomium** documentation :

> WSLit() is a special helper function that lets you declare WebString literals. Most of our API uses UTF-16 strings (wrapped with WebString) but we added WSLit() so you can declare ASCII C-strings with minimal fuss.

Comment: What character encoding does Awesomium's `WSLit` expect?

Comment: Is it even remotely possible that you may encounter non ASCII data? If you do, do you care what happens?

Comment: A quick Google shows that you should probably be using `WebString` with Unicode strings, e.g. `WebURL url(WebString(ui_path.c_str()))`.

Comment: @David: URI's can consist of Unicode characters (see [An Introduction to Multilingual Web Addresses](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/) for reference).

Comment: @IInspectable I know that. My question was rhetorical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WSLit` is meant to construct a `WebString` object from an ASCII string. Since you don't want to construct a `WebString` from ASCII, but rather have a UNICODE string from the beginning, you simply don't need to use `WSLit` at all.

The following line of code constructs a `WebURL` from a `std::wstring`:

```
WebURL url(WebString(ui_path.c_str()));
```

---

As pointed out by Remy Lebeau this may not compile for any given compiler or compiler settings. `WebString` has an `explicit` constructor taking a `const wchar16*`. *Platform.h* defines `wchar16` as

```
typedef unsigned short wchar16;
```

Depending on your compiler and compiler settings, this may or may not be the same as `wchar_t`. When compiling with the Microsoft compiler using the command line option [/Zc:wchar_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh8che7s.aspx), `wchar_t` is interpreted as a native data type. This is a different type from `unsigned short`, and the explicit constructor of `WebString` requires an additional cast:

```
WebURL url(WebString(reinterpret_cast<const wchar16*>(ui_path.c_str())));
```

Implicitly invoking the conversion constructor of `WebString` using the following syntax is not possible, since it is declared `explicit`:

```
WebURL url(reinterpret_cast<const wchar16*>(ui_path.c_str()));
```

Comment: This leads to a compiler error : src/main.cc(53) : error C2248: 'Awesomium::WebURL::WebURL' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Awesomium::
WebURL'

Comment: You are well advised to add the appropriate `#include` directives. If your compiler fails to construct the temporary `WebString` object from the `const wchar_t*`, be explicit. I have updated the answer.

Comment: `std::wstring::c_str()` returns a `const wchar_t*`, but `WebString` does not have a constructor that accepts a `wchar_t*` as input.  It has a constructor that accepts `const wchar16*` instead, but `wchar16` is a typedef for `unsigned short`, so you need a type-cast: `WebURL url(WebString((const wchar16*)ui_path.c_str()));` or simply: `WebURL url((const wchar16*)ui_path.c_str());`

Answer (score -2):

If the question is "convert std::wstring to const char*", I usually use this function and it works fine:

```
std::string wstringToString(const std::wstring& in){
     std::string result(in.begin(), in.end());
     return result;
}
```

And then, you can get `char*` by calling `result.c_str();`

Comment: please, can you share your wisdom and let me know how this corrupts data?

Comment: Any character that is not an ASCII character in the source string will get garbled up.

Comment: It is ok, I did not consider that possibility, for example: "korean" characters. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
std::wstring ui_path = L"file:///" + install_path + L"/util/ui/index.html";
std::string cui_path( ui_path.begin(), ui_path.end() );
WebURL url(WSLit(cui_path));
view_->web_view()->LoadURL(url);
```

However, IMHO, if Awesomium is intended to run under Windows, the WSLit constructor should support either a std::wstring or wchar_t * argument.